# how to calculate the sum of amount for same names in ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

here is app.js

```
AllServices.teamAllDataFunction1(User)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.User.data=response.data['DeatilTeam'];
            console.log($scope.User.data);
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < ($scope.User.data).length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt($scope.User.data[i].dp_inst_pending) || 0;
            }
});
```

here m getting all data in which so many records having same name but differnt pending amount, so i want to show only single name and the summation of there penging amount, so that i can show it in single row. I'm not getting how to achieve it.. please help me..

here is html,

```
<table ng-table>
                <tr>
                    <th>advisor_name</th>
                    <th>totalpending</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="data in User.data" ng-if="data.dp_inst_pending && data.dp_inst_pending == 0">
                    <td>{{data.AdvisorName}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.dp_inst_pending}}</td>  
                </tr>
            </table>
```

[image]

in this way i 'm getting data

Comment: What error or issue you are facing?

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you mean by 'I'm not getting to to achieve it.' It's not because 'DeatilTeam' is spelt wrong is it? Also have you setup a controller & injected your service? I cannot see a controller setup in your HTML where your scope would be defined & which would be used to access the data back from the service

Comment: Please show me the data?

Comment: m not getting errors...i want to bind the same advisornamesinto one name but sum of their amount

Comment: yes i have injected the service

Comment: please help me ............

Comment: hello is anyone there?????

Comment: Post the sample response data from server

Comment: Are you sure that there will be only one name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code has few generic issues, let's resolve that first.

First of all, assuming your data.dp_inst_pending is Integer, you have used it directly in ng-if. In that case, if someone actually has zero pending amount it won't be displayed.

Secondly, you want to calculate sum of pending amount for those accounts which have same name. for that you will have to run a double for loop. One to check names and other to add pending amount if name is same. I have created one sample for the same, which i think satisfies your requirements. Please go through it and optimize as required.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("MyController", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.User = {};
    $scope.User.data = [{
      "advisor_name": "Test1",
      "dp_inst_pending": 300
    }, {
      "advisor_name": "Test2",
      "dp_inst_pending": 0
    }, {
      "advisor_name": "Test1",
      "dp_inst_pending": 500
    }, {
      "advisor_name": "Test2",
      "dp_inst_pending": 600
    }, {
      "advisor_name": "Test1",
      "dp_inst_pending": 15
    }, {
      "advisor_name": "Test2",
      "dp_inst_pending": 150
    }, {
      "advisor_name": "Test3",
      "dp_inst_pending": 30
    }];
    $scope.User.summedData = [];
    var sums = [];
    var advisorNames = [];


    for (i = 0; i < $scope.User.data.length; i++) {
      var key = $scope.User.data[i].advisor_name;
      if (advisorNames.indexOf(key) >= 0) {} else {
        var sumOfKey = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < $scope.User.data.length; j++) {
          if ($scope.User.data[j].advisor_name == key) {
            sumOfKey += $scope.User.data[j].dp_inst_pending;
          }
        }
        sums.push(sumOfKey);
        advisorNames.push(key);
      }
    }
    $scope.Test = {};
    $scope.Test.data = [];
    for (k = 0; k < sums.length; k++) {
      $scope.Test.data[k] = {
        "advisor_name": advisorNames[k],
        "dp_inst_pending": sums[k]
      }
    }
    console.log(sums);
    console.log(advisorNames);
    console.log($scope.Test.data);
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <table ng-table>
      <tr>
        <th>advisor_name</th>
        <th>totalpending</th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="data in Test.data">
        <td>{{data.advisor_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.dp_inst_pending}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

I am not optimizing it, as it should be done by you.

Comment: Let me know if anything else is required on this or you have any doubts